# Control not recognizing edited state - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple control form, where I am allowing the user to edit fields.

If the user has edited a field, we do not update the value from the database and mark it as so.

If the user *has not edited a field*, we retrieve the latest value from the database and update the corresponding control.

Currently this does not work. About half the time the control is still "replaced" even after the user has modified it.

Here is my code:

```
  @foreach (var row in Model.controls)
            {
              <input type="text" name="@row.Name" id="@row.NameID" value="@row.Value" edited="0" class="form-control data-field" onfocus="return ControlEdited(this.id)" style="width: 300px" />

           }
```

First, we generate the controls. These are dynamic and formed with a foreach from my viewmodel.

This function below is called using onFocus when a control is edited:

```
   function ControlEdited(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('edited', 1);
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

Now to the tricky part - this function below I call is only supposed to replace and rewrite fields that have not been edited. Yet it only works some of the time. It commonly replaces fields that have been edited.

```
function UpdateControls() {

    $(".data-field").each(function () {
        var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var edited = $(this).attr('edited');
        var stationID = document.getElementById('stationDD').value;

        if (edited == 0) { //control has not been edited, so we will access database and replace value if needed.
            var url = "/Manager/UpdateControlsFromDB/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { name: nameAttr, station: stationID },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {

                        document.getElementById(id).value = data;
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Issue updating the page controls from database. Information: " + response.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            //do nothing, user edited field so we do not update from database
        }

    });
}
```

I am very confused. How is this edited variable and the corresponding code not working? onFocus event is called on each editor, and this should immediately render the "edited" value to 1, and prevent the UpdateControls() method from touching them.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

debug and console.log each variable in the updateControls function and see if something goes wrong

i have tried your approach and seems to be working fine on my end

```js
function ControlEdited(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('edited', 1);
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function editTxt(){
        $('.inp').each( function (){
            if($(this).attr('edited') == 0){
                   $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users',
                    cache: true,
                    success:(res)=>{
                        $(this).val(res['first_name'])
                    }
                })
            } else {

            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" edited="0" class="inp" id="1" onfocus="return ControlEdited(this.id)" value="Default">
    <input type="text" edited="0" class="inp" id="2" onfocus="return ControlEdited(this.id)" value="Default">
    <input type="text" edited="0" class="inp" id="3" onfocus="return ControlEdited(this.id)" value="Default">
    <input type="text" edited="0" class="inp" id="4" onfocus="return ControlEdited(this.id)" value="Default">
    <button onclick="editTxt()">Check</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the example. Ill check out the variables while debugging and see what I can find!